# Message cleared message not sending when only clearing a single message

Tags: discord, discord.js

Here are my message successfully cleared messages. The first one works fine and I can get the embedded but when I try to clear only a single message, the message deletes fine but I'm not receiving a success message. Thanks in advance.

```
await message.channel.messages
.fetch({ limit: parseInt(args[0]) + 1 })
.then((messages) => {
    message.channel
        .bulkDelete(parseInt(args[0]) + 1)
        .then(() => {
            if (args[0] > 1) { 
                let clearMessages = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .addField("Success:",`Cleared ${args[0]} messages.`)
            .setColor("#000000")
            message.channel.send(
                clearMessages
            ).then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
              })
              .catch
                            
            } if (args[0] === 1) {
                let oneMessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .addField("Success:",`Cleared ${args[0]} message.`)
            .setColor("#000000")
            message.channel.send(
                oneMessage
            ).then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
              })
              .catch
            }
        })
```

Comment: This is not related to the issue you are encountering: consider using a ternary operator to check the value of `args[0]` and adding the 's' to 'message' to make your code more readable and cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `===` to compare `args[0]` (string) with `1` (number) will always evaluate to false. Wrap `args[0]` with `parseInt` to get a number out of `args[0]`.

Also, for more readable code, I suggest checking if `args[0]` is 1 or larger than 1 with a ternary operator inside the message embed field.

```js
`Cleared ${args[0]} message${parseInt(args[0]) === 1 ? '' : 's'}.`
```

is much more readable than the original code posted above.

Comment: Or you could just evaluate the string `"1"`… or use the normal comparison (==)

Answer (score 1):

When you are comparing args, you must use both strings, or both numbers.

```js
if(parseInt(args[0]) > 1) {
//...
}
```

And for [strict comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) (`===`)

```js
if(args[0] === '1') {
//
}
//also works with (args[0] == 1) and (parseInt(args[0]) === 1)
```

> The strict equality operator (===) checks whether its two operands are equal, returning a Boolean result. Unlike the equality operator, the strict equality operator always considers operands of different types to be different.
> -MDN